# Setting up VPS to allow only subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, vps, domains

I would like to know how to configure my VPS so that it's **only** accessible using `sub.domain.com`, and **not** `domain.com`. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Point the domain.com A record else where and the www. at your servers IP address.

A better option would be to 301 redirect the domain.com to the sub.domain.com so if a user types in domain.com it shows as sub.domain.com

Comment: the reason I'm doing this is so that clients who I build sites for cannot see the sites until they are final. therefore, I cannot have domain.com simply redirect to sub.domain.com - i need domain.com to show a 'page not found', while i test using something like test.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

SImple: do not define an IP address for domain.com, only one for sub.domain.com.

Comment: this didnt work - i think vhost config needs to be adjusted. I tried changing `ServerName  domain.com` to `ServerName  sub.domain.com` which also did not work.

Comment: It does work. You *also* need to change the ServerName but the right thing to do is to have no address record for domain.com in the DNS. So, two things to adjust.